# Search columns of one file to a different column on another file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have two files of varying columns.

`File1`:

```
pears   are fruits
apple   is  fruit
carrot  is  veg
celery  is  vegetable
oranges are fruits
```

`File2`:

```
fruits apple   mycode is #q123c# for apple
fruits pears   my code is #q432c# for juicy
veg    celery  my code value is #q989c# for vegetables
veg    spinach code is #q783c# and is a type of vegetable
fruits papaya  i have code #q346c#
vegie  lettuce code #q445c# is vege
```

Need Ideal Output file:

```
Q432C pears fruits
Q123C apple fruit
Q---C carrot veg
Q989C celery vegetable
Q---C oranges fruits
```

Need to compare column 1 of File1 to column 2 of `File2`.
If there is a match, print the q-to-c codes inside the two # fields in `File2`,
Otherwise print an empty code of `q---c`.
And convert the q-c codes into upper case.

I expect the output to have the same number of lines as `File1`.

Ideally, the output file should have the q-to-c code from `File2` then follow by appending the corresponding lines from `File1`.  But at the moment, I have only worked out how to chop the q-to-c codes out of lines that matched in `File2` and made it into upper case:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1]=1; next } ($2 in a) {print $0} ' File1 File2 | sed -e 's/.*#\(.*\)#.*/\1/' | tr [a-z] [A-Z] > outputFile
```

... could someone please help?  I am new to `awk` and scripting.

I was going to do a join after getting the above results, but then I risk not joining the correct q-to-c codes to the right lines because my resulting output file does not have as many lines as `File1`.
I'm open to other solution than `awk`.

If someone could help, I would really appreciate this. :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I usually try to edit question of new comers , but please try to first of all read the [tour] to know a bit better about stackexchange, Second, [edit] your question so it's actually unreadable. You can jump line with double space at the end of line and you can quote text and format text. Please show a little effort in the formatting, as is I don't even want to read it.Edit: Lucky you,  Kusalanandamake it way better

Comment: Thanks Kiwy.  Yes I realised the formatting was terible, so i was also trying to edit it, I just couldn't do it as fast as you did. Thanks heaps, and please accept my sincere apologies.

Comment: I know no chats, just questions and answers. But thank you @Kusalananda for editing my original question so quickly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With single **`awk`** command:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{
         match($0, /#q[0-9]{3}c#/);
         fruits[$2] = substr($0, RSTART + 1, RLENGTH - 2);
         next
     }
     { print ($1 in fruits? toupper(fruits[$1]) : "Q---C"), $1, $3 }' file2 file1
```

The output:

```
Q432C pears fruits
Q123C apple fruit
Q---C carrot veg
Q989C celery vegetable
Q---C oranges fruits
```

Comment: Thanks RomanPerekhrest.  Had to replaced the regexp match from `/#q[0-9]{3}c#/ `to `/#q[0-9][0-9][0-9]c#/` and your answer then worked perfectly.  Otherwise, output was missing the QxxxC codes for rows 1, 2 and 4.  Thanks heaps.

Comment: @achinghead Good! If this solves your issue, please consider [accepting the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).